# Did default number of AWS Elastic Block Store change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

Previously we had default limit for number EBS volumes as 5000.
[image]

However recently it has been removed from AWS docs.[image]

Reference Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_ebs

Could someone tell me what is the default limit for number of EBS Volumes now?

Comment: I believe the number of volume limitation is no longer in use and instead moved to in terms total provisioned capacity (storage/IOPS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS now limits your EBS volume usage based upon two factors: Provisioned IOPS and total storage for each storage type.

You can check your account limits from the AWS Console:

- Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/
- From the navigation bar, select a region
- From the navigation pane, choose Limits (left hand column)
- Locate the resource in the list. The Current Limit column displays the current maximum for that resource for your account

[Amazon EC2 Service Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html)